# ruby metacharacters with matching string

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a program where two strings are entered. If they match it returns the number of positions where they contain the same length 2 substring.

for example:string_match('xxcaazz', 'xxbaaz') → 3 "xx" "aa" "az"
My question is what metacharacters  should i use to validate

here is what i have come up with

```
puts "enter word"
a = STDIN.gets
a.chomp!
puts"enter word"
b = STDIN.gets
b.chomp!
if a == /word/ or b == /word/ then 
  puts str.match(/{a} {b}/) + "equal"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER:

( Still spiked, but better )

```
first_word = 'xxcaazz'.split('')
second_word ='xxbaaz'.split('')

first_word_length = first_word.length
second_word_length = second_word.length

if [first_word_length, second_word_length].min == first_word_length
  inner_word = second_word
  outter_word = first_word
else
  inner_word = first_word
  outter_word = second_word
end

outter_word_length = outter_word.length - 2

word_matches = 0

(0..outter_word_length).each do |character|
  if "#{outter_word[character]}#{outter_word[character + 1]}" == "#{inner_word[character]}#{inner_word[character + 1]}"
    puts "#{outter_word[character]}#{outter_word[character + 1]}"
    word_matches += 1
  end
end

puts "Found #{word_matches} matches"
```

ORIGINAL SPIKE:

This may get you off to a good start ( though it's by no means bullet proof, just a quick spike ):

```
first_word = 'xxcaazz'.split('')
second_word ='xxbaaz'.split('')
first_word_length = first_word.length

(0..first_word_length).each do |character|
  if "#{second_word[character]}#{second_word[character + 1]}" == "#{first_word[character]}#{first_word[character + 1]}"
    puts "#{second_word[character]}#{second_word[character + 1]}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Unpack 'a2X' means extract the 2 bytes, then rewind 1 byte:

```
first_word = 'xxcaazz'
second_word ='xxbaaz'
tokens = first_word.unpack 'a2X' * (first_word.length - 1)
# => ["xx", "xc", "ca", "aa", "az", "zz"]
tokens.flat_map{|m| second_word.scan m}
# => ["xx", "aa", "az"]
```